# Javascript socket list listeners

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

Using `socket.io-client` I want to know what events are being listened to, for debugging.

Is there a way using `socket.io` to list all of the current "on" listeners?

**EDIT:** code & clarification

This is my code:

```
//starts with
socket.on("somethingRecieved", this.somethingRecieved.bind(this));

//sometime after
socket.removeListener("somethingRecieved", this.somethingRecieved.bind(this));
```

I'm looking for something that will reply with something like:

```
{
    somethingRecieved: function(){...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```js
var socket = io('localhost');
console.log(socket.__proto__);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

Comment: It logs the socket prototypes, not the "on" listeners